# Sill Plate not Lining up with Foundation Wall

Tags: wood, framing, carpentry

I am in the process of building a one level home in PA. After the formed concrete walls were poured and the framing began, I noticed that on one side of the house that the sill plate was flush with the edge of the foundation wall in the rear, but, by the time the sill plate got to the front it was 2 1/2" away from the edge of the foundation wall. In summary, the sill plate walks from flush with the foundation wall at the rear to 2 1/2" at the front. This happens over about a 50' run.

Any thoughts or concerns would be appreciated. Any recommendations on what sorts of questions to ask when I meet the site supervisor on Monday?

Comment: It appears that you've asked the same question twice.

Comment: Yes, in a different area. I am hoping for answers.

Comment: Most of the folks around here spend the weekends tackling their own home important projects, so don't expect too many answers until Monday afternoon.

Comment: Also, if you just want to add more tags to a question you've asked.  You can use the edit feature to include them, instead of asking duplicate questions.